# How to create Jolt Specification in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am converting JSON data into nested JSON using **`JoltTransformation`** processor in `Apache Nifi`.

This is the **JSON Input**, which has to convert into the nested format.

```json
[
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Hyundai",
    "Model1": "Verna",
    "Sub-Model1": "2018"
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Hyundai",
    "Model1": "Creta",
    "Sub-Model1": "2015"
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Hyundai",
    "Model1": "Aura",
    "Sub-Model1": "2022"
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A2",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Toyota",
    "Model1": "Fortuner",
    "Sub-Model1": "2020"
  }
]
```

The JSON nested **Output I want** from JOLT Spec. I am grouping the data on the combined keys of `Company`, `Model1`, and `Sub-Model1`. And finally, want this kind of nested JSON data. I tried finding Jolt Spec Documentation.

```json
[
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "Company": {
      "Hyundai": [
        {
          "Verna": [
            {
              "2018": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Creta": [
            {
              "2015": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Aura": [
            {
              "2022": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A2",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "Company": {
      "Toyota": [
        {
          "Fortuner": [
            {
              "2020": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**I have tried** this so far but it's not generating the desired output.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,Agent)@(1,location)@(1,Company)@(1,Model1)@(1,Sub-Model1).&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "agent.[#2].Agent",
        "*": {
          "$": "agent.[#3].location",
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "agent.[#4].Company",
              "*": {
                "Model1*": "agent.[#6].Company.[#4].Sub-MOdel1.[#2].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(0,Agent)": "@(1,Agent).Agent",
        "@(0,Location)": "@(1,Agent).loc_id",
        "Sub-Model1": "@(1,Agent).Company.@(1,Company).@(1,Model1).@(1,Sub-Model1)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // A1, A2
        "loc_id": "ONE",
        "Agent": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // A1, A2
        "*": "[#2].&",
        "Company": {
          "*": { // Hyundai
            "*": { // Verna
              "*": { // 2018
                "@": "[#6].&4.&3[#3].&2.[#1].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": []
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**First operation: `shift`**

We should add all items according to the `Agent` value to have them in the same array and we will use the index of the array for the future.

**Second operation: `cardinality`**

We have some arrays that have multiple same values because of the result of the previous operation. We can change them to normal their value by the `cardinality` operation and `ONE` to make them just one value instead of an array of values.

**Third operation: `shift`**

Bring `Model1` and `Sub-Model1` values in the array.

**Fourth operation: `modify-overwrite-beta`**

Give empty array value `[]` to `Sub-Model1` values.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I would like to know if you can add description so that I can understand it better and also where to change if I want to add more list within SUB-MODEL1 like more nested with sub-model2[] something.

Comment: @Destiel Description added for all steps. I highly recommend to you, run the specs step by step and see what exactly happened. Good luck.

Comment: I want to understand this line in detail " "Sub-Model1": "@(1,Agent).Company.@(1,Company).@(1,Model1).@(1,Sub-Model1)" " like How this (.) dot thing is working here?

Comment: @Destiel Dot `.` is known by JOLT. You can say create an object with a value of `@(1,Agent)` and then create an object with a `Company` key in it and ...

Comment: Hi, Do you know how can I call a conditional loop on invokeHTTP? I have to call an API in NIFI untill its condition is true. Eg: I call the API with an ID and got SUB-ID as the result of API, now that SubId will be the ID for the next call and will keep calling the API till we got the Empty value.

Comment: @Destiel As far as I know about that, you can use the **UpdateAttribute** processor and get the `ID` as a variable in your flowfile and then use it in another **InvokeHttp** (second processor, is not the first one) and then create a loop by adding a condition with **RouteOnAttribute** and set your condition (until your `ID` is not empty with `nifi expression language`).

Comment: Hi, I have another case for the jolt spec, when Model1 or subModel1 (both or one) will be empty, it is not printing data for those rows, I want to print the data even if model or submodel col is empty. I have attached a new code block for the same.

Comment: Dear @Destiel, please ask another answer to the new question you have. Chatting in the post's comments is not good. Please roll back your answer to the last things that the answer matched with that. I'll be always there for you if you have any questions in the JOLT tag :)

Comment: I'm making another question. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76032991/how-to-consider-null-values-in-jolt-spec-in-nifi  .....Hi this is the new question I have made.