# How to consider null values in jolt spec in NIFI?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

For the given CSV data, the jolt spec is not considering the null values.

I have 2 points to consider.

1. if submodel1 is empty then it should atleast print till model1.
2. if model1 is empty then it should print till company.(Agent A3 case)

Here null will be empty value in CSV

**CSV DATA**

```json
[
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Hyundai",
    "Model1": "Verna",
    "Sub-Model1": "2018"
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Hyundai",
    "Model1": "Creta",
    "Sub-Model1": null
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Hyundai",
    "Model1": "Aura",
    "Sub-Model1":null 
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A2",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "Toyota",
    "Model1": "Fortuner",
    "Sub-Model1": "2020"
  },
{
    "Agent": "A3",
    "Location": "L1",
    "Company": "BMW",
    "Model1": null,
    "Sub-Model1": null
  }
]
```

**Jolt SPec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(0,Agent)": "@(1,Agent).Agent",
        "@(0,Location)": "@(1,Agent).loc_id",
        "Sub-Model1": "@(1,Agent).Company.@(1,Company).@(1,Model1).@(1,Sub-Model1)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // A1, A2
        "loc_id": "ONE",
        "Agent": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // A1, A2
        "*": "[#2].&",
        "Company": {
          "*": { // Hyundai
            "*": { // Verna
              "*": { // 2018
                "@": "[#6].&4.&3[#3].&2.[#1].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": []
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**: This is json I'm getting but I want to print the available data.
**For creta, AURA nothing has printed and BMW is not printed also**

```json
[
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "Company": {
      "Hyundai": [
        {
          "Verna": [
            {
              "2018": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A2",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "Company": {
      "Toyota": [
        {
          "Fortuner": [
            {
              "2020": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A3",
    "loc_id": "L1"
  }
]
```

**Expected output**

```json
[
  {
    "Agent": "A1",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "Company": {
      "Hyundai": [
        {
          "Verna": [
            {
              "2018": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Creta": [
            {}
          ]
        },
        {
          "Aura": [
            {}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A2",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "Company": {
      "Toyota": [
        {
          "Fortuner": [
            {
              "2020": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Agent": "A3",
    "loc_id": "L1",
    "Company": {
      "BMW": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan- The expected output? Because what I am getting is already appended

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Expected Output appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *else case* of the ***notNull*** function within a **modify** transformation, and partition the attributes into sub-objects by their respective **`Agent`** values such as

```json
[ 
  { // apply conversion for the null elements of "Model1" and "Sub-Model1" attributes
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*odel1": ["=notNull", " "] // the values are overwritten provided the attributes have null values
      }
    }
  },
  { // group the objects by their "Agent" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Agent": "@1,Agent.&",
        "Location": "@1,Agent.loc_id",
        "# ": "@1,Agent.@1,Company[0].@1,Model1[].@1,Sub-Model1"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the keys of the objects 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": ""
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the attributes with " " keys which had been used above for transformation as the else case
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            " ": "",
            "*": {
              "*": {
                " ": ""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": ["= ", []]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // reduce the number of the repeating components to one
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Agent": "ONE",
        "loc_id": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I want to put Agent and loc_id above company,model and submodel. How can I do so?Rest its working as I needed Thankyou so much

Comment: You're welcome @Destiel , sorting would a bit tricky. If the arrays have common key, the we can individually write them as the three attributes within an added last spec :  `{
    "operation": "sort",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Agent": "[#2].&",
        "loc_id": "[#2].&",
        "theArray": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }`, but `{
    "operation": "sort"
  }` might be a straightforward option only to take `Agent` to the top.

Comment: Using this sort Agent reached to top but loc_id not?

Comment: Yes exactly, since we have no array's key name as I explained. the `"*"` wildcard instead of `"theArray"` wouldn't work, but hardcoding as `"Hyundai|Toyota|BMW"` would work ... @Destiel

Comment: what is the meaning of .@1 in this line  ("# ": "@1,Agent.@1,Company[0].@1,Model1[].@1,Sub-Model1")

Comment: @Destiel  `@1,Agent` is exactly identical to `@(1,Agent)` which appears in your jolt spec as well, just removed the redundant brackets. We just copy the value of Agent after traversing 1 level(traversing colon(`:`)).